# Angular 4 form validation with model not working

Tags: angular, validation

I am creating my first form in Angular 4, and want to do both input and form validation.  I am trying to use a template-driven form.  I created the form like this:

```
<form novalidate [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="description">Description</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" name="description" maxlength="255" minlength="5" required [(ngModel)]="myobj.description"  #desc="ngModel" >
    </div>
    ...
```

And the associated component is:

```
export class SamplecComponent {

  // Create an object with default values in the object
  myobj = MyObject.constructDefault();

  // Not sure why I need this...
  form = new FormGroup({ });

  submitForm() {
    console.log(this.form.valid);
    console.log('in submitForm');
  }
```

I can confirm if my description inputs is in a VALID or INVALID state, but when I submit the form the this.form.valid value is always TRUE.  Why?

As well, why do I need to create an empty FormGroup?  Every example I've found sets initial values for inputs, but since I'm using a model already populated this doesn't make sense.

-----UPDATE-----
I added

```
#myform="ngForm"
```

to the form selector and tried to access the form state in the .ts file using

```
console.log(this.myform.valid);
```

but when I click submit the console says:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'valid' of undefined

on the html template line where I defined myform.

Comment: are you using template driven forms or reactive ? if template then you can reference form via local variable like #myForm="ngForm" and check if its valid or not and if you are using reactive forms you need to define validations for elements like this this.myForm = new FormGroup({
    'name': new FormControl('', [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.minLength(4)
    ]),

Comment: You are confused between 2 directions: template-driven form (using `ngModel` in template) and model-driven form (aka reactive form, which needs `new FormGroup(...)` in the code. Given that, it's your best interest to look-up articles about these 2 styles and decide to go with either. One of them could be found here http://blog.angular-university.io/introduction-to-angular-2-forms-template-driven-vs-model-driven/

Comment: Take a look: https://angular.io/guide/forms

Comment: I am using template driven form (and have updated my question).

Comment: I've reread the documentation a few times and I'm not clear on this: Can I create a template driven form, and then add reactive validators?